# add a value for the status parameter?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to set up a scriptable post bot as an exercise in learning basic HTTP authentication. The only thing missing in the script is to add a value for the status parameter (it'll be the text that you put into the post) but I have no clue what that means

googled thru many posts, sites, but could not figure out what the status parameter is or what the value for it is

```
var request = require('request')
var username = 'myusername'
var password = 'mypassword'
var options = {
url: 'https://www.SiteToPostTo.com/',
auth: {
user: username,
password: password
}
}

request(options, function (err, res, body) {
if (err) {
console.dir(err)
return
}
console.dir('headers', res.headers)
console.dir('status code', res.statusCode)
console.dir(body)
})
```

an alternate code would seem to be this one, but i am unclear where the username/password info would go?

```
const requestUrl = url.parse(url.format({
protocol: 'https',
hostname: 'yoursite.com',
pathname: '/the/path',
query: {
key: value,
status: 'message to post'
}
}));

const req = https.get({
hostname: requestUrl.hostname,
path: requestUrl.path,
}, (res) => {
// ...
})
```

Comment: I didn't got the problem. Aren't you receiving the actual status code or trying to understand the http code meaning itself?

Comment: i made an edit, with an alternative code that has the status parameter but i am unclear on where the username/password info would be put into the alt code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear from your question, you mention,

> The only thing missing in the script is to add a value for the status parameter (it'll be the text that you put into the post)

I assume from "it'll be the text that you put into the post", that you want to know how to send a `request body` in your API call.

Here is how you would send a `request body` with your POST method call using `request` module,

```
const request = require("request");

const username = "myusername";
const password = "mypassword";
const options = {
  url: "https://www.SiteToPostTo.com/",
  auth: {
    user: username,
    password: password
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    key1: "val1",
    key2: "val2"
  })
};

request(options, function(err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.dir(err);
    return;
  }
  console.dir("headers", res.headers);
  console.dir("status code", res.statusCode);
  console.dir(body);
});
```

Just like how you specify the `url`, `auth` keys in the `options` object you would also specify the `request body` as a value to the `body` key.
Bear in mind that the `request body` should be provided as a string in the case of a JSON object, that's why we use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: thanks, yes your code seems to work although it's still getting the error "Cannot find module 'request' ". By "(it'll be the text that you put into the post)", I meant that that is the message that the bot will post

Comment: @randomDev83746 You are getting ```Cannot find module 'request'``` error because you haven't executed ```npm install request``` to install ```request``` npm module? Check your ```package.json``` dependencies

Comment: thank you, that fixed it. I also changed the value of the key to request, and it worked. Thanks for your help, sorry if I didn't word the question right as I am pretty new to all this

Comment: Ok, I will do that now, altho I don't think it recorded my upvote since it said I have a rep of less than 15